# Kentico upload attachment permissions

Tags: kentico

I have an editable image web part, and I'm trying upload an image as an attachment. The event log is showing me this:

> Message: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
>
> Exception type: System.Exception
>       Stack Trace: 
>       at MultiFileUploader.ContentUploader.CheckAttachmentUploadPermissions(UploaderHelper
>   args)
>       at MultiFileUploader.ContentUploader.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

This is happening on my local dev machine, and I'm about to test this on a dev VM I have. Also, I'm using the default Administrator account.

AND, I can upload an attachment in an Editable Text web part.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things which could cause this:

- User running the website/application pool does not have permissions to read/write to the directory on the server
- IIS is not configured properly with authorization
- Kentico is not configured properly (based on the error, it's most likely not this)

Comment: I thought attachments were stored in the DB? IIS_IUSER as full control to the CMS folder.

The odd thing i can upload an attachment in a Edit Text webpart.

Comment: It's a desktop iis issues. the dev vm is fine.

Comment: Even if the attachments and files are to be stored in the DB, the file is still uploaded to the server temporally and then removed after it is stored in the DB.

Comment: Try giving "Full" access to the whole web project to the user account under which your AppPool is running.